# Pager, edit links to pages (numbers)

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, pager, layered-navigation

I have a problem when I select a layered navigation and I try to switch to the next page...

my pager link to an url like that http://www.examplesite.com/category.html**#%21___SID=U&manufacturer=102&p=2** but it's disabling layered nav.

I guess Right url should be: http://www.examplesite.com/category.html**?manufacturer=102&p=2** (this one is working right)

I checked toolbar.phtml, pager.phtml but I dont know why is displaying "#%21__...." instead of "?"

What file I should edit?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem. Adding some **str_replace("#%21","?","...")**

First I edited my toolbar.phtml (/app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml)

line 55

```
<option value="<?php echo str_replace("#%21","?", $this->getLimitUrl($_key)) ?>"<?php if($this->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif ?>>
```

line 72

```
<a href="<?php echo str_replace("#%21","?",$this->getModeUrl($_code)) ?>" title="<?php echo $_label ?>" class="<?php echo strtolower($_code); ?>"><?php echo $_label ?></a>&nbsp;
```

line 103

```
 <option value="<?php echo str_replace("#%21","?",$this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc')) ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
```

---

And my pager.phtml

line 69

```
    <li><a href="<?php echo str_replace("#%21","?",$this->getPageUrl($_page)) ?>"><?php echo $_page ?></a></li>
```

I hope this helps someone who is having the same problem I had.